# Laravel not getting the correct and related results

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm trying to create an image-library for my App, so I can request images from my Laravel API.

The images are seperated into types depending on their location in the app, like "sidemenu", "topbanner" etc.

Some images can take additional attributes like "url", "text" etc. These attributes will be different depending on the `image-type`. So an image of the type "side-menu" might take an attribute called "font-color" or something like that.

My db-structure looks like this:

[image: DB structure]
So the idea is to get all images that has an `image_type` with a specific slug like "sidemenu". Then I would like to join all the `image_type_attributes` on the `image_type` and finally join their values.

I have split the values and `image_type_attributes` into their own tables, so I can use the attributes as a template for which attributes my users can fill in when uploading an image.

This almost works, but something is wrong with my code/relations because the relation between images and image_value is ignored, so the values I end up getting back is just the first instance belonging to the given `image_type` in the database - this should be the values related to the images.
(right now I get the values entered for my first image on all my images)

These  are my models:

**Image**

```
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'images';


    public function attributes(){
        return $this->type->attributes();       
    }

    public function type(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ImageType::class, 'image_type_id');
    }

}
```

**ImageType**

```
class ImageType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'image_type'; 


    public function images(){
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }

    public function account(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Account::class);
    }


    public function attributes(){
        return $this->hasMany(ImageTypeAttribute::class);
    }

}
```

**ImageTypeAttribute**

```
class ImageTypeAttribute extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'image_type_attribute'; 


    public function value(){
        return $this->hasOne(ImageValue::class, 'image_type_attribute_id');
    }

}
```

**ImageValue**

```
class ImageValue extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'image_value'; 

}
```

My controller:

```
// 1. Get all active images with some slug ex. "sidemenu" 
// and get the image-attributes and values as well

$images = Image::whereHas('type', function($query) use ($image_slug, $slug){
    $query->where('slug', $image_slug);
})
->with('attributes')
->where('active', 1)        
->get();

// 2. Loop through all images, and get the image attribute-names and values
$image_array = [];
foreach($images as $image){
    $image_array['image'] = $image->image;

    foreach($image->type->attributes as $attribute){
        $image_array[$attribute->name] = $attribute->value->value;
    }
}
return $image_array;
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show us a `dd($images)` and `dd($attribute->value)` on the foreach loop? Also, I think you should eager load `value` (`->with('attributes.value'`) [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: What i get in the end is this: (the images are right, but the values on image 2 is wrong)
 `{
image: "storage/images/599eb9b09c6f0.jpg",
header: "header1",
link: "url-for-first-image"
},
{
image: "storage/images/599eb889a3d7c.jpg",
header: "header1",
link: "url-for-first-image"
}`

Comment: I tried adding the with('attributes.value') but its the same as before.
I get a value but just not the right one

Comment: from which table you are getting link and all that??

Comment: What's the output of `dd($attribute->value)`?